# Vue.js how to change computed property from a method?

Tags: vue.js, methods, computed-properties

For example, I have a button that has a property `:disabled="isDisabled"`
where `isDisabled` is a computed property that returns a Boolean.
Also, in the code, I have a method from which I want to change the computed property value. For example, in the case of doing some operation (e.g sending a request to a server), I want to make a button inactive. But then I want to let the computed property doing their job in case any action would be applied in a range of its authority. So I want to explicitly redefine the value returned by the computed property.

```html
<button
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  :disabled="isDisabled"
   @click.prevent="submitted"
>
```

```js
computed: {
     isDisabled: function() {
     //... some code
     return true
     }
}
```

Which is the right way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Neither.  Consider adding an additional state that is flagged while your http request is in-flight and reset after it is completed that is used in conjunction with your isDisabled flag.  If there are two different conditions...create two different properties.

Comment: @DavidL Thank you for your answer. Yeah, in my head that makes sense.  Did you mean that I need to use an additional flag like that :disabled="isDisabled && isLoading"? So if my isDisabled is false in a moment when all fields validation passes and isLoading is true, how to beat those values to make : disabled true again. Or you mean to create one property and update it from different places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you typically want to have a computed property handle just one job.  If you add a data property that specifically deals with your in-flight http request and use both, you get fine-grained control over your disabled state.

```html
<button
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  :disabled="isDisabled || isLoading"
   @click.prevent="submitted"
```

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        isLoading: false
    }
},
computed: {
     isDisabled: function() {
     //... some code
     return true
     }
},
methods: {
    makeHttpCall: function () {
        this.isLoading = true

        axios
            .get('url')
            .finally(function () {
                this.isLoading = false
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. Yes, this is the exact solution to my question.

Comment: Happy to help!!